# JWT Token Signature could not be verified

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token, jwt

Solutions form other topics did not help me, so I created new ask.
Each time when I want to poke(GET) my protected route with header with token I get: "Token Signature could not be verified in BaseMiddleware.php" . Also my generated tokens don't match at jwt.io
I have the same 'secret' in `jwt.php` as JWT_SECRET in `.env`

I've tried to `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan jwt:secret`

I have custom claims in User model:

```
public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
return ['firstname' => $this->firstname,
'lastname' => $this->lastname,
'email' => $this->email];
}
```

I use `Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware to protect route. `api.php`:
`Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->get('users','UsersController@getAllUsers');`

`'jwt.auth'` is added into `Kernel.php`.

I just stucked at the begining. My repo is bmbBAMBUS/vetpet at git, it's public since it's just begining.

`Composer version 1.5.2`
`PHP 7.1.10`
`"tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1"`

Comment: Any ideas ? I can't resolve it